# Need free English dictionary or Corpus, ultimately for a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, dictionary, corpus

I'm trying to find a free downloadable dictionary (or Corpus might be the better word) which I can import into MySQL. I need to words to have the type (noun, verb, adjective) associated with them. Any tips on where I can find one? I found one several years ago that worked nicely, but I no longer have it around.

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 2):

[Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Main_Page) has public domain books you can download.

This includes ['The Gutenberg Webster's Unabridged Dictionary'](http://www.gutenberg.org/etext/673), but nothing modern, and not in a format immediately suitable for import into a MySQL database.

Not without some work, anyway. What was the one you found "years ago" ?

Answer (score 2):

- [Kevin's Word List Page](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/) includes a part of speech database.
- [Wiktionary](http://www.wiktionary.org/)
- The 1913 edition of [Webster's Dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webster%27s_Dictionary#1913_Edition), now in the public domain

Answer (score 1):

http://www.desiquintans.com/nounlist looks pretty good... I searched 'nouns.txt' and it came right up.

Comment: As of today, this link leads to a 404 error.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, I fixed the link.