# Free String Dictionary (Nouns)

Tags: dictionary, resources

I am looking for a free (downloadable) dictionary of nouns to use as an actual word generator - similar but not the same as captcha's.

Does anyone know if anything like this is available?

Thanks,

Kyle

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892802/need-free-english-dictionary-or-corpus-ultimately-for-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Kevin's Word List Page](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/) includes a part of speech database.
- [Wiktionary](http://www.wiktionary.org/)
- The 1913 edition of [Webster's Dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webster%27s_Dictionary#1913_Edition), now in the public domain

Comment: Thanks a ton Josh, that parts of speech database is perfect.